# Functional difference between select and poll system calls in unix

Tags: c++, linux

I am pretty sure people are going to be hard on this question saying it is a repeated one. But i intended to ask something specific. I faced a scenario in which a select call failed to get the handels where as poll system call could recognize the handles.

I am not finding any soothing reason behind it.
Let me explain the scenario-
I was trying to get a scocket client to register to a server which was not in the same machine.
When the client is in the same machine select system call works efficiently. But when it is not a part of the same machine it fails and poll works.

Any general resoning behind this ?
(Note:I am using ACE wrapper library )
Added
Code snippet

```
           int noOfHandles = 4;
            int handles[4];

            int result = thedserver->get_handles(handles,noOfHandles);

            if ((result < 0 ) || (noOfHandles <= 0))
            {
                    return -1;
            }
            ACE_Handle_Set dsdHandleSet;

            for( int i = 0 ;  i < noOfHandles ; i++)
            {
                    cout << "handles: " << handles[i] << endl;
                    dsdHandleSet.set_bit(handles[i]);
            }
            cout << "noOfHandles: " << noOfHandles << endl;
            ACE_Time_Value tv1(60, 0);

            while(1)
            {
                    int res = ACE::select(dsdHandleSet.max_set() + 1, &dsdHandleSet, 0, 0,&tv1);
                    cout << "res: " << res << endl;
            }
```

Comment: Can you post code which demonstrates this problem please?

Comment: Please provide a small code snippet as to how you were using each. `select()` should wait until one or more file descriptors becomes ready or until the timeout you pass it happens. If you don't pass a timeout it should wait forever. I've never seen `select()` fail and I'd like to see how you were using it.

Comment: @Mike added the relevant code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'm not sure what your code is trying to do. I don't know why you'd `while(1)` the select function, but there's a number of problems here. Make sure you read the man for [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)

First, you set a timeout. If you want to wait forever until the handle is ready, pass `NULL` for the timeout value.

Second, after every run, `select()` modifies the timeout, so you want to use it, you have to rewrite it. You can use `pselect()` to avoid this.

Finally you should be using `FD_ZERO()` and `FD_SET()` to clear and set file descriptors before calling select.

It's possible that some of this is abstracted for you in the ACE library, I'm not familiar with that, but in general these are the pieces that I see that are wrong/missing.

Comment: Thanks for the above! But these are handled as you said by ACE library... and wabout the while loop, it was intentionally put to test the select time out scenario..

Comment: @samairtimer - OK, yeah I was thinking that might be the case. Have you tried the `select()` with a `NULL` timeout to see if that fixes your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect that you either had an error in the code or the file descriptor was outside of FD_SETSIZE (which would be an error in the code). On the systems where I've looked at how select/poll are implemented, select is implemented by translating the arguments internally in the kernel into an equivalent poll call (or vice versa on older systems). In other words - there should be no functional difference.

Comment: I agree with you ! But it does not seem to be the same. Added a code snippet which had no errors in the compilation or runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the ACE library, but the `select` system call *modifies* its arguments. You need to recreate the sets before each call to `select` in the loop.

Comment: Similar code is working nice in case of a client within the local machine.